# Metrics for $\bar{\mathbb{R}}^2 (\bar{\mathbb{R}} = [-\infty, \infty] )$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

What are some examples of metrics for the set $\bar{\mathbb{R}}^2$, where  $\bar{\mathbb{R}} = [-\infty, \infty]$?
For any such metric defined on $\bar{\mathbb{R}}^2$, will $\lim_{(x,y) \to (\infty, \infty)}xy\sin{\frac{1}{xy}}=1$ always hold?

Comment: Do you want the metric to induce the standard topology on $\bar{\mathbb{R}}^2$?

Answer (score 2):

I assume the topology on $\bar{\mathbb R}^2$ is the “same” like $[0,1]^2$ and not like $\mathbb C \cup \{\infty\}$.

1. Take any metric $d$ on $\bar {\mathbb R}$ you like. Then, 
   $$ d_2(x,y) = d(x_1, y_1) + d(x_2,y_2) $$
   is a metric on $\bar {\mathbb R}^2$.
2. For any such metric $d$ that induces the standard topology on $\bar{\mathbb R}$ we have
   $$(x,y) \to (\infty, \infty) \implies xy\to \infty. $$
3. We have $z \sin(1/z) \to 1$ for $z\in \mathbb R$ and $z\to \infty$.

Piece them together to get your claim.